# smiles faces in angular1

Tags: angularjs, emoji

I need to set smile faces in comments in my project. I have check the `angular-emoji-picker` this works fine when i made test project with ng-strap method but stop working when i integrated in my project. its smile faces popup doesn't work

[image]

why doesn't it work when i integrated it? is there a better picker that I can use?

```
<body ng-controller="myController">


<span style="margin: 0 20px;" emoji-picker="message" placement="right" title="Emoji" recent-limit="12"></span>

  <p><strong>Imagify filter</strong>: <span emoji-removable="message" ng-
   bind-html="message | imagify"></span></p>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-emoji/lib/emoji.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js">
 </script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-
 strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-emoji-picker/dist/js/emoji-picker.js"></script>
```

here is module

```
 angular.module('myModule',['vkEmojiPicker','mgcrea.ngStrap'] )
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {

             $scope.message = "String including Emoji codes :smiley:";

 });
```

Comment: There's a strong connection between emoji's and cancer. I'd advice you to not use emoji's.

Comment: what u said ? @HarrySvensson

Comment: I say that you shouldn't implement emoji's. It's like autism cause vaccine. We don't need vaccine. These are dangerous stuff you know.

Comment: u have gud sense of homour :)

Comment: @Asad you can try [Emoji picker](https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup/)

Comment: have u tried this ? @TejinderSingh is there imagify and picker both available ?

Comment: Yes, it has many filters you can use, I have tried this. it worked fine in `angularjs` but it didn't work fine in `ionic`

Comment: @Asad you can also check (https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker)

Comment: this one is in simple javascript not in angular :(

Comment: @Asad but the pervious one will work that i sent earlier

Comment: is ther eworking demo for that ? @TejinderSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used emojione with angularjs here is my working fiddle 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lqc20js/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#emojionearea2").emojioneArea({
pickerPosition: "right",
tonesStyle: "radio"
 });
```